# APIGEE revision comparisons

Tags: api, apigee

I recently started using APIGEE.  I want to compare two revisions. One way is to download both the revisions and then compare them in a Compare plugin. Is there a simpler way to do it, with out the hassle of downloading it and comparing it on the fly. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While the Apigee UI is really handy, it's not a full development environment.  I'd recommend using something like Eclipse to manage your files in local development, and check your filesystem into a git repo. Then you have all your deltas and rollbacks at your fingertips.

Comment: Can we set up a local instance without opening ports and connect it to the APIGEE which is already present in the server? Please advice.